# Mobile Redirect not working

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile-browser

I got this JavaScript code off of http://detectmobilebrowser.com/, but it doesn't redirect my phone's browser to the proper page. I put it in the `index.htm` file, which should branch off to `main.htm` or `miniMain.htm` depending on the browser using it, but it always goes to `main.htm`

```
function mCheck(a, mobilePage, page) {
  if (/android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|opera mobile|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4)))
    window.location = mobilePage
  else
    window.location = page;
}
mCheck(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera, "miniMain.htm", "main.htm");
```

Comment: what kind of phone do you have?

Comment: LG Optimus T, running Android Froyo. I tested its built-in browser and Opera Mobile

Comment: have you tried making it a full url redirect, using `http://example.com/miniMain.htm` and `http://example.com/main.htm` instead of just the page names?

Comment: th..... that worked..... submit it as an answer. I wanna give you points. Also, I want to remove some from mine. >.<

Comment: haha, ok, adding now with a bit more info...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you should try setting absolute URIs on window.location instead of relative ones:

```
window.location='http://example.com/mypage.html'
```

You can also set the Location object's href property:

```
window.location.href='http://example.com/mypage.html'
```

However, what I would recommend for detecting mobile devices is a **server-side** solution, because you just can't rely on JS being available/turned on for redirects. If you have PHP, the best solution I've found, and used in production sites, is this php script: http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi (note the trailing `s` and `.mobi` as compared to the site where you got your script). If you wanted to write this in a server-side language (apache, node.js, nginx, asp, whatever) you could try some of the scripts on the site you originally visited ( http://detectmobilebrowser.com ), though I've never tried those and can't vouch for efficacy.

Comment: thank you! And, unfortunately, even if I had PHP installed, my site has a for-profit section, so I can't use that